# javascript: for (i in str), nested, weird results outside of FF?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cross-browser, nested-loops

I'm rather confused at the moment, could someone explain this one to me? Maybe it's something small I'm oblivious to, but I'm confused as to why this isn't resulting as I expect it to.

I have created a samples to show the issue I'm seeing...

[Sample 1](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yV5yf/1/)

```
var dataString = "abc";

document.write(" This is a test ... " + "<br/>")
for (i in dataString ) {
    document.write("<br/> +" + dataString[i] + ": ")
    for (k in dataString ) {
        document.write(" ="+dataString[k] +", ");
    }
}
​
```

Now, my results in **Chrome** are:

```
This is a test ... 

+a: 
+b:
```

In **FireFox** are: (This is the result I expected)

```
This is a test ... 

+a: =a, =b, =c, 
+b: =a, =b, =c, 
+c: =a, =b, =c,
```

Results in **IE8** are:

```
This is a test ...
```

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here? Have I missed something critical?

Note:
You can translate strings to arrays across browsers using `"abc".split("")` as per [this example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XWbZr/1/), just remember that this is no longer a string and now if you output it, it will be output as an array `a,b,c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in dataString ) {
    document.write("<br/> +" + dataString[i] + ": ")
```

It is not part of the JavaScript standard(*) that strings should have their characters accessible as numbered properties; this is an extension originally introduced by Mozilla. Consequently `dataString[i]` will be `undefined` on older browsers including IE<8.

To access a character in a string properly you should use `charAt`.

For the same reason, `for...in` over a string won't iterate over the indexes in all browsers.

And even if it did, it would be the wrong thing to use, because `for...in` is for enumerating properties in an `Object` (`{}`) map, *not* iterating over sequences. `for...in` should not be used on an `Array` or `String` as you will get all the members of that instance, not just numeric-indexed ones, and there's no guarantee you will get them in any particular order.

For `Array` and `String` the correct loop is the old-school `for i` loop. And you should use `var` even if it's a global variable.

```
document.write(' This is a test ... <br/>');
for (var i= 0; i<dataString.length; i++) {
    document.write('<br/> +'+dataString.charAt(i)+': ');
    for (var k= 0; k<dataString.length; k++) {
        document.write(' ='+dataString.charAt(k)+', ');
    }
}
```

(*: well... not in ECMAScript Third Edition. The new Fifth Edition states that Strings have ‘array index names’, which might be an endorsement of this feature. Seems a little unclear)

Answer (score 1):

according to W3C :

> The for...in statement loops through the elements of an array or through the properties of an object.

Your dataString as a `string` type and nothing else, the result you have is interpreted differently on each browser.

- IE : dataString isn't an object : >
  "I don't loop" (not obvious, datatype doesn't match)
- FF :
  dataString is a ??? : "I iterate on
  each character, both and combine it" (very obvious)
- Chrome : dataString is an array of
  character : "I iterate on each
  character". (not obvious because a string can be considered as a character array, but still...)

Obvious but still normal.

Comment: Interesting, and it can all be resolved if the dataString stores the value as such : `var dataString = ["a", "b", "c"];`

Comment: @user257493: You could also use `var dataString = "abc".split("")`